# При отрицании субъект выражен не подлежащим, а дополнением в родительном падеже

Tags: синтаксис, грамматика, подлежащее, дополнение

*...чтобы не возникало вопросов.*

*...чтобы не возникали вопросы.*

В чём различие между двумя способами построения конструкции и в чём разница в семантике? А также в каких случаях характерна такая постановка дополнения в родительном падеже при отрицании? Возможна ли такая конструкция при единственном числе существительного?

*...чтобы не возникало проблемы.*

Answer (score 3):

Речь идет не о подлежащем, а о субъекте действия.

(1) **Чтобы не возникали вопросы:** субъектом действия и подлежащим являются ***вопросы***.

(2) **Чтобы не возникало вопросов/вопроса:** безличное предложение, подлежащее отсутствует, но **субъект действия подразумевается или может быть обозначен дополнением** (чтобы ни у кого не возникало вопросов, чтобы у меня не возникало вопросов).

Безличный вариант встречается намного чаще, так как **действие  в этом случае представлено как некий стихийный процесс,** результатом которого и являются вопросы.

Особенно часто безличная форма встречается   в придаточных цели с союзом ЧТОБЫ, так как безличные (инфинитивные) предложения вообще характерны для таких конструкций.

Comment: Я так понимаю, число существительного значения не имеет для выбора двусоставного или безличного типа предложения? Кстати, влияет ли на выбор степень определённости субъекта по условию контекста: если подразумеваются конкретные вопросы, уместно двусоставное предложение с подлежащим, а, когда имеются в виду просто какие-либо вопросы, предпочитается безличное? Также уточните, пожалуйста, почему вы написали *безличные (инфинитивные)*, ведь у нас речь идёт о безличных глаголах, а не об инфинитивах?

Comment: 1) Число существительного значения не имеет. 2)  Ограничения при выборе вариантов есть. Например,  в некоторых СПП безличный вариант смотрится неестественно, так как элемент стихийности  там  отсутствует, например: Я  хочу, чтобы не возникало вопросов... Лучше так:  я хочу, чтобы не возникали вопросы... Также  согласованное определение нежелательно в безличных конструкциях, например: чтобы не возникало таких (лишних) вопросов. 3) Выходи пораньше,  чтобы успеть на поезд. Это пример безличного инфинитивного предложения.